# How to correctly pass map parameters to a global variable of a Jenkins shared library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cicd

I have the following shared library

```
//my-shared-library
//vars/buildMyApp.groovy

def call(Map pipelineParams) {

    pipeline {
        agent any
        
        stages {
        
            stage('A') {
                  agent {label "${pipelineParams.agent}"}
                  steps {
                    script {
                       //do something here
                    }
                  }
            }
            
            stage('B') {
                  agent {label "${pipelineParams.agent}"}
                  steps {
                    script {
                       //do something else here
                    }
                  }
            }
            //and other stages here
    }
    
}
```

I am trying to call this global variable from my pipeline script

```
//Jenkinsfile
@Library("my-shared-library") _
pipeline {

    parameters {
    string(name:"fruit",value:"orange",description:"a fruit")
    string(name:"vegetable", value:"carrot", description: "a vegetable")
    }
    stages{
        stage('call script') {
        steps {
            script {
                Map config = [agent: "Build-Node", fruit: "${params.fruit}", vegetable:"${params.vegetable}"]
                buildMyApp config
            }
        
        }
        
        }
    
    }


}
```

This does not work as Map parameters cannot be passed to the global variable so easily. I tried the following -

```
//vars/buildMyApp.groovy

def call(Map pipelineParams) {

    return { //"return" instead of pipeline block
        agent any
        
        stages {
        
            stage('A') {
                  agent {label "${pipelineParams.agent}"}
                  steps {
                    script {
                       //do something here
                    }
                  }
            }
            
            stage('B') {
                  agent {label "${pipelineParams.agent}"}
                  steps {
                    script {
                       //do something else here
                    }
                  }
            }
            //and other stages here
    }
    
}
```

and in my Jenkinsfile -

```
@Library("my-shared-library") _

pipeline {
  parameters {
    string(name: "fruit", value: "orange", description: "A fruit")
    string(name: "vegetable", value: "carrot", description: "A vegetable")
  }

  stages {
    stage("call script") {
      steps {
        script {
          def pipelineParams = [            fruit: "${params.fruit}",            vegetable: "${params.vegetable}",            agent: "Build-Node"          ]
          def pipelineScript = buildMyApp(pipelineParams)
          pipelineScript()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work either. I get an error saying - hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: buildMyApp

Is there a solution to this? I really need to take the parameters from the user and pass it to the shared library as a Map. As I have around 19 parameters, its best that I use Map. Therefore my main Pipeline structure more or less is fixed.

What I also tried: call the buildMyApp job as build job. I cannot pass Map value there straightforward either.

Comment: The error message does not match the provided code.

Comment: I think your problem may start before passing Maps and parameters. Can you execute a hard-coded pipeline that you return from a function? If so, paste the code.